# Vue Server Side Rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

If we convert SPA application to SSR+SPA when a page is rendered on server the data is loaded from vuex store by dispatching actions that make http calls through axios to api on localhost.

Or that data is need to be loaded from database and some how passed to vue and prevent dispatches of store actions?

In traditional application I will retrieve that data direct from data base and not make get request.

It is normal?
This is the way?

Nuxt also use get request and not database queries:

```
export default {
  asyncData({ params, error }) {
    return axios
      .get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
      .then(res => {
        return { title: res.data.title }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
      })
  }
}
```

I can do that without nuxt in serverPrefetch().

On other hand if I do something like

```
export default {
  asyncData({ req, res }) {
    and here if I access database like in node server
   (req, res) => {
      **select something from database **
      return User.findOne({ });
   }
  }
}
```

Back end sensitive code will be visible in front end script?!

Comment: I think you should use NuxtJS to do what you want

Comment: I know about nuxt by I think it do the same?

Comment: https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/ and https://ru.nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ always in examples is used axios and not database query

Comment: If I understand well I need to make 1-10 http requests on server side to render a page?! This will eat cpu and memory? But what will be if the site will be accessed by 1000 users per minute/ second?

Comment: or I need to combine requests for all components in one when page is rendered on server

Comment: 1-10 requests? what?

Comment: each component on the page receives data using API calls through axios (menu, blok1, blok2, ..) when is rendered on server side, but it can get that data direct from database. That make the app to work very bad. Now I have one axios request per page. It serve 300 requests from 10 users in one minute, but a site on php more bigger serve in 5 seconds. Or I need to use nodejs+nginx to test it?

Comment: I test it in development mode, in production mode is: Time taken for tests:   23.632 seconds and not 70. Php site now show: Time taken for tests:   24.111 seconds, but it is based on CMS with many sql queries

Answer (score 0):

By using nuxt you mean:

/plugins/api-context.server.js

```
export default (context, inject) => {
  inject("api", async (controller, method, params) => {
    try {
      let api = require("../api/" + controller.replace(/^\/+|\/+$|\.+/g, ""));
      return await api[method](params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  });
};
```

/nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/api-context.client.js",
    "~/plugins/api-context.server.js"
  ]
```

Now the this function.$api will directly call the controller method on the server, and this on the client.$api send http request via axios.

How to do the same without nuxt?